# Which units of measure are used in the Here Traffic Flow API

Tags: here-api

I read the developer documentation but still I can't find which units are used for
speedFlow
speedUncapped
location length, etc.
The API response for speeds are in the range of 2.5-3.7, too low to be miles per hour.
Does anyone know which units are used in the API response. They don't offer tech support for trial accounts.
Thank you.

I read the developer documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Here Traffic API v7 - Speeds

A current flow object contains 3 speed values:

```
•   freeFlow - the reference speed (in meters per second) along the roadway when no traffic is present.
•   speed - the expected speed (in meters per second) along the roadway; will not exceed the legal speed limit.
•   speedUncapped - the expected speed (in meters per second) along the roadway; may exceed the legal speed limit.
```

Here developer documentation
https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/dev_guide/topics/concepts/flow.html

Comment: Yes, They recently updated the documentation to include it.